# Using git-filter-repo to add file to oldest commit

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

The github repo for git-filter-repo has a demo python app that is used to add files to the oldest commit, https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/contrib/filter-repo-demos/insert-beginning, has a comment saying that it could be done as a one-liner:

```bash
git filter-repo --force --commit-callback "if not commit.parents: commit.file_changes.append(FileChange(b'M', $RELATIVE_TO_PROJECT_ROOT_PATHNAME, b'$(git hash-object -w $FILENAME)', b'100644'))"
```

Given the mix of tools being used here, this isn't making a lot of sense to me.  How would the command look running on windows 10, adding a .gitignore file or LICENSE file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I would use `git-filter-repo` for this; you can just use `git rebase`.

1. Run `git rebase -i --root`
2. In the result pick editor, change `pick` to `edit` on the first commit.
3. Back at the shell prompt, `git add` the file(s) you want to add.
4. Run `git rebase --continue`